# tab activity in toolbars? or should i say, drawer + tabbed activity in a tool bar. How can i achieve this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button, android-tabbed-activity

so i am trying to create like a social media kind of tool bar, check this out. [This is like the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh8I1.png)  that includes a navigation drawer slider and when you swipe around, it becomes just like a tabbed activity.

*(sorry for only 1 picture, stackover flow is not allowing me to post more than 3 links)*

I have been thinking what to use and ways to do it.

Here are my conclusions

1. Create a drawer and customise the toolbar by adding tabs into it. If tabs cannot be added, i will try to add image button and then use it along with fragments. Sliding effect might be compromised.
2. Create a tabbed activity, set the icons and try to get the slider/drawer to work. Which i think might be possible. I just thought of another idea which VSCO app was using, slider drawer to be placed in a floating action button. Brilliant, this might work.

I am leaning more on choice 2 btw.

GUYS I NEED SOME INPUT, CRITICISE ME. GO.

*whatever unsure of can be clarified with me of course.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add TabLayout inside the toolbar with DrawerLayout. See below XML it work for me.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:tabMode="fill"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="@color/WhiteColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```